# C# - Pass data back from ThreadPool thread to main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-3.5, queue, threadpool

Current implementation: Waits until `parallelCount` values are collected, uses `ThreadPool` to process the values, waits until all threads complete, re-collect another set of values and so on...

Code:

```
private static int parallelCount = 5;
private int taskIndex;
private object[] paramObjects;

// Each ThreadPool thread should access only one item of the array, 
// release object when done, to be used by another thread
private object[] reusableObjects = new object[parallelCount];     

private void MultiThreadedGenerate(object paramObject)
{
    paramObjects[taskIndex] = paramObject;
    taskIndex++;

    if (taskIndex == parallelCount)
    { 
        MultiThreadedGenerate();

        // Reset
        taskIndex = 0;
    }
}

/*
 * Called when 'paramObjects' array gets filled
 */
private void MultiThreadedGenerate()
{
    int remainingToGenerate = paramObjects.Count;

    resetEvent.Reset();

    for (int i = 0; i < paramObjects.Count; i++)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                int currentIndex = (int) obj;       

                Generate(currentIndex, paramObjects[currentIndex], reusableObjects[currentIndex]);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref remainingToGenerate) == 0)
                {
                    resetEvent.Set();
                }
            }
        }, i);
    }

    resetEvent.WaitOne();    
}
```

I've seen significant performance improvements with this approach, however there are a number of issues to consider:

[1] Collecting values in `paramObjects` and synchronization using `resetEvent` can be avoided as there is no dependency between the threads (or current set of values with the next set of values). I'm only doing this to manage access to `reusableObjects` (when a set `paramObjects` is done processing, I know that all objects in reusableObjects are free, so `taskIndex` is reset and each new task of the next set of values will have its unique 'reusableObj' to work with).

[2] There is no real connection between the size of `reusableObjects` and the number of threads the `ThreadPool` uses. I might initialize `reusableObjects` to have 10 objects, and say due to some limitations, ThreadPool can run only 3 threads for my `MultiThreadedGenerate()` method, then I'm wasting memory.

So by getting rid of `paramObjects`, how can the above code be refined in a way that as soon as one thread completes its job, that thread returns its `taskIndex`(or the `reusableObj`) it used and no longer needs so that it becomes available to the next value. Also, the code should create a `reUsableObject` and add it to some collection only when there is a demand for it. Is using a Queue here a good idea ?

Thank you.

Comment: What version of .Net are you on?

Answer (score 5):

There's really no reason to do your own manual threading and task management any more.  You could restructure this to a more loosely-coupled model using [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx) (and possibly [System.Collections.Concurrent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) for result collation).

Performance could be further improved if you don't need to wait for a full complement of work before handing off each `Task` for processing.

TPL came along in .Net 4.0 but was [back-ported to .Net 3.5](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/parallelextensions/thread/aa1dd834-3c3d-409b-907e-196ee8f427bf).  Download [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx).

Comment: +1 I did not know about the back port, so thanks for the info.

Comment: @Brian - I had seen ref to this but not tracked it down before, it's very useful if well-hidden.